# how to download a CSV file returnd by ajax or post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv, download

I'm sure the answer to my question is somewhere in this website, but I couldn't manage to find an answer that fixes my problem.

I'm trying to download a `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` response content as CSV. I know these jquery functions don't download automatically despite a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="name.csv"` header, for security reasons.

But here are my constraints :

- The response can be extremely large, depending on the filters the user set.
- I don't want to clear the current page.
- I can't create a server-side CSV file.
- I'm not using `<a>` elements but `<button>`

Does anyone know how to do this in a clean and decently fast manner ?

Comment: Already answered, refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638343/download-csv-file-as-response-on-ajax-request

Comment: You just have to prepare the download url and access it like an anchor, leave the rest to the serverside code.

Comment: Note this [specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29939024/519413) in the duplicate. For this to work you will need to create the file in-memory on the server and send it in the response.

Comment: I forgot to tell I use `button`. My bad. anyone has a quickfix for that ?