# Exporting model data to csv file using Python Django not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to create a but to export some data in my database to a csv file. It hits the correct part of the if statement but no CSV file is being downloaded.

```py
# =================================
#  CSV Import/Export Functionality
# =================================
@login_required
def exportData(request, setCode):
    current_user = request.user

    if request.GET.get('product-type') == 'Cards':
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment;filename=ExportData-" + setCode.upper() + "-" + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S") + ".csv"
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow(['setCode', 'id', 'number', 'name', 'rarity', 'convertedManaCost', 'colors', 'standard', 'foil'])
        SQL_EXPRESSION = "CAST((REGEXP_MATCH(number, '\d+'))[1] as INTEGER)"

        for cards in inventory_cards.objects.all().filter(user_id=current_user.id).extra(
            select={'int': SQL_EXPRESSION}).order_by('card_id__set_id__code', 'int', 'card_id__number').values_list(
                'card_id__set_id__code', 'card_id', 'card_id__number', 'card_id__name', 'card_id__rarity', 'card_id__convertedManaCost'):
            writer.writerow(cards)
        return response
    elif request.GET.get('product-type') == 'Tokens':
        pass
    elif request.GET.get('product-type') == 'Sealed':
        pass
```

```js
// ======================
//  Export Function
// ======================
function exportData(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/magic/sets/" + setCode + "/export-data/?product-type=" + product_type,
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token,
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: Are you hitting this endpoint through a browser?

Comment: yes, I have a button that calls js function. An ajax request to the endpoint. Ill add the js to the question.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638343/download-csv-file-as-response-on-ajax-request) might help

Comment: you can use django-import-export it's easy and clean