# How to download a csv file with symfony 4?

Tags: csv, symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to download a csv file with symfony 4.
I read the documentation.
I understood that I must normalize my objects and encode in csv.

My controller:

```
/**
* @Route("/export.csv", name="exportcsv", options={"expose"=true}, methods={"GET","POST"})
*
**/
public function exportcsv(){
   $sessionuser = $this->session->get('user');
   $user = $this->finduser($sessionuser);
   $datas = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Object::class)-> findBy(['Event'=> $user->getEvent()]);
   $encoders = [new CsvEncoder()];
   $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
   $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
   $csvContent = $serializer->serialize($datas, 'csv'); 
   return new Response($csvContent);
}
```

When i try to go on this route, i can see in my browser all my datas in the good format for a csv.
For example, I have:

NameColumn1, NameColumn2, NameColumn3

Data1Column1, Data1Column2, Data1Column3

Data2Column1, Data2Column2, Data2Column3

I read that it's the good format to create a csv file.

I would like to know I to generate the csv file.

If anyone have a solution, it would be awesome. I'm on it for a week and I'm totally lost.

Thanks.

EDIT: By the way I tried this solution [How to force download a .csv file in Symfony 2, using Response object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307048/how-to-force-download-a-csv-file-in-symfony-2-using-response-object)
It download a file but it's empty.

Comment: please see [how to serve files](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/http_foundation.html#serving-files)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force download a .csv file in Symfony 2, using Response object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307048/how-to-force-download-a-csv-file-in-symfony-2-using-response-object)

Comment: I tried these 2 solutions. I see a file dowloading but it's empty.

Comment: Doesn't $user->getEvent() throw an error? It seems like $user would be null here.

Comment: @CHE6yp i don't put all the code but it's indeed $user is defined before. I will edit my question.

Comment: Update your question and show the changes you made based on the answer you linked.  All you should have to do is to set the two headers on the response object per the linked answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

In fact, i  had 2 problems:
The first was I should set the headers in the correct format.
The second was Visual studio code who didn't read the code between 2 commented sections of code.

For information, this is my new code. If it can help anybody ;)

```
 /**
 * @Route("/export.csv", name="exportcsv", options={"expose"=true}, methods={"GET","POST"})
 *
 **/
public function exportcsv(){
  $sessionuser = $this->session->get('user');
  $user = $this->finduser($sessionuser);
  //search all the datas of type Object
  $datas = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Object::class)-> findBy(['Event'=> $user->getEvent()]);
  // normalization and encoding of $datas
  $encoders = [new CsvEncoder()];
  $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
  $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
  $csvContent = $serializer->serialize($datas, 'csv');

  $response = new Response($csvContent);
  $response->headers->set('Content-Encoding', 'UTF-8');
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
  $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=sample.csv');
  return $response;
}
```

Thanks to everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this:

[How to create a link that download a file in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910112/how-to-create-a-link-that-download-a-file-in-symfony)

But for this to work you need to put the content into an temporary csv file.

Hope this helps, stay safe!